# Rabbit MQ Advice Architecture Multithreading JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I'm new to rabbit MQ i want to use it in my app and i need some clarifications : 
- First My app is an api used as (maven dependency in multiple java projects)
- the api role is to notify users when some events are detected in those projects
- notifications will be in 2 ways by email and sms 
- every time an event is detected the api is writing it in rabbit mq Queues and senders (standalone projects for notifying, one for emails and another for sms)
- first as a beginner i thought of it as 2 QUEUES related to a channel, one queue for SMS sender as consumer  and another for EMAIL sender as a consumer, but how can i manage multithreading, when there are a lot of messages in QUEUES.
i know my understanding of rabbit MQ is very weak but i have not a lot of time and i need help where to go and how to learn it fast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to have only one exchange for notifications and bind it to 2 queues, each for SMS and e-mail notifications.
[Good starting point.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) You can read up on routing (how bindings work etc.).